# Issue with AES encrypt/decrypt - Objective-C -> Python (Tornado)

Tags: python, objective-c, tornado, encryption

I have a problem for several days and don't know how to fix it. I'm making an app that sends a NSDictionary to a server with Python-TornadoWeb. Well, I send the data encrypted with AES 256 and the problem is to decrypt.

**Objective-C code for encrypt (key = "0123456789abcdef")**

```
// Copy the key data, padding with zeroes if needed
char key[kKeySize];
bzero(key, sizeof(key));
memcpy(key, keyData, keyLength > kKeySize ? kKeySize : keyLength);

size_t bufferSize = [self length] + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t dataUsed;

CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(decrypt ? kCCDecrypt : kCCEncrypt,
                                 kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 key, kKeySize,
                                 NULL,
                                 [self bytes], [self length],
                                 buffer, bufferSize,
                                 &dataUsed);

switch(status){
    case kCCSuccess:
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:dataUsed];
    case kCCParamError:
        NSLog(@"Error: NSDataAES256: Could not %s data: Param error", decrypt ? "decrypt" : "encrypt");
        break;
    case kCCBufferTooSmall:
        NSLog(@"Error: NSDataAES256: Could not %s data: Buffer too small", decrypt ? "decrypt" : "encrypt");
        break;
    case kCCMemoryFailure:
        NSLog(@"Error: NSDataAES256: Could not %s data: Memory failure", decrypt ? "decrypt" : "encrypt");
        break;
    case kCCAlignmentError:
        NSLog(@"Error: NSDataAES256: Could not %s data: Alignment error", decrypt ? "decrypt" : "encrypt");
        break;
    case kCCDecodeError:
        NSLog(@"Error: NSDataAES256: Could not %s data: Decode error", decrypt ? "decrypt" : "encrypt");
        break;
    case kCCUnimplemented:
        NSLog(@"Error: NSDataAES256: Could not %s data: Unimplemented", decrypt ? "decrypt" : "encrypt");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Error: NSDataAES256: Could not %s data: Unknown error", decrypt ? "decrypt" : "encrypt");
}

free(buffer);
```

Well, the encrypted data sent to the server and do the following

```
class LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):

    # Body
    body = self.request.body
    print "--------------------------- Before decrypt ---------------------------"
    print body
    print "----------------------------------------------------------------------"

    # Decrypt
    key = '0123456789abcdef'
    mode = AES.MODE_CBC
    decryptor = AES.new(key, mode)
    bodyDecrypted = decryptor.decrypt(body)
    print "--------------------------- After decrypt ----------------------------"
    print bodyDecrypted
    print "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

And the result is:

--------------------------- Before decrypt ---------------------------

BU??c???
        ?????d?PP??I?G?'??

--------------------------- After decrypt ----------------------------

?Ƒg,??e#???
?(?>97R???
           ??

As you see, is decrypted incorrectly. If you send unencrypted, everything works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that the encoding between the Objective-C and Python are the same. When dealing with encryption at the application level I like to convert and send everything  in hexadecimal format and then convert it again just to make sure that encoding is not an issue.

By the way, what version of Python are you using? (3.0+ and above use unicode)

Comment: I use NSUTF16StringEncoding, but do not know if I do something else in the Python server ...

Comment: Yeah. It sounds like an encoding issue to me. Try using ascii or utf8 on both sides for consistency.